# Prove that $\rho_n \star f \to f$ in $L^p(R^N)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $\rho \in L^1(R^N)$ with $\int_{}^{} \rho=1$ .Set $\rho_n(x)=n^N\rho(nx)$. Let $f\in L^p(R^N)$ with $1\leq p<\infty$.  Prove that $\rho_n \star f \to f$ in $L^p(R^N)$.

My try:

Since $f \in L^{p}(\mathbb{R^N})$, there exists $f_1 \in C_{c}(\mathbb{R^N})$ such that $|f-f_1|_{L^{p}} \lt \epsilon$ for a given $\epsilon \gt 0$. I add and subtract $\rho_n *f_1$. The problem is to show that $\rho_n *f_1$ and $f$ can be arbitrarily small either by adding and subtracting terms or directly. I am trying to bring in mollifiers somehow since for a sequence of mollifiers $\mu_n$, I know that $\mu_n*f \to f$ uniformly as $n \to \infty$. I am unable to proceed from here.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to start by showing that $\|\rho\star f\|_{p}\le \|\rho\|_1\|f\|_{\rho}$, which holds for $1 \le p \le \infty$, but you don't need this for $p=\infty$. For $p=1$, this is fairly standard. If you're not sure how to estimate that, let $q$ be conjugate to $p$ so that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ and write
$$
     \left|\int \rho fdx\right| \le \int |\rho|^{\frac{1}{q}}\{|\rho|^{\frac{1}{p}}|f|\}dx
$$
For any $R > 0$,
\begin{align}
   \|(\chi_{|x|\ge R}\rho_n)\star f\|_p & \le \|\chi_{|x|\ge R}\rho_n\|_1\|f\|_p
     \\
    & = \int_{|x|\ge R}|\rho_n|dx\|f\|_p \\
    & = \int_{|x| \ge nR}|\rho|dx\|f\|_p\rightarrow 0 \mbox{ as } n\rightarrow\infty.
\end{align}
The remaining piece is $(\chi_{|x| \le R}\rho_n)\star f$, which can be studied for continuous $f$.

Comment: Hello@TrialAndError Could I ask you something about distribution theory?

Comment: @Evinda : Yes, but it would best to post as a general question.

Comment: That is my question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1717696/show-fundamental-solution
$$$$
Do you have an idea?